# Generate Valid JSONP with multidimensionally Array in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

am try to generate a dynamic JSONP echo, but i get an error in my inspector tool after js ajax call :

> `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery191019304498913697898_1365868235193 is not defined index.php:1`

PHP:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');

$array = array();
array_push($array, array('name' => 'A', 'host' => 'A.com'));
array_push($array, array('name' => 'B', 'host' => 'B.com'));

//$jsonp = json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$jsonp = json_encode($array);


if(isset($_GET['callback']))
{
    echo $_GET['callback'].'('.$jsonp.')';
}
else
{
    echo $json;
}

?>
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    username: username,
    password: password,
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    ifModified: true,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            console.log(value['name']);
        });
    }
});
```

Ajax Call Response:

```
jQuery191019304498913697898_1365868235193([{"name":"A","host":"A.com"},{"name":"B","host":"B.com"}])
```

Have you any idea?
Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this would be much of a problem, but you're missing your semi-colon: echo `$_GET['callback'].'('.$jsonp.');';`

Comment: Also, you are printing to response (and then to the JS) the callback GET param. That's why the javascript is complaining about the "Uncaught ReferenceError". Don't print that value unless is a valid variable in your javascript.

Comment: @navnav: I add the missing semi-colon, but same error :/

Comment: @ricardohdz: Sorry, my English is not so well, but can you explain?

Comment: you are missing a closing parenthesis on your array_push

Comment: @1337holiday: Sorry, its correct in my PHP-File. I have edit some values and removed accidentally the parenthesis.

Comment: You are printing the ajax callback reference id to the JS again and since that variable is not in the javascript is complaining about that. Try removing the "$_GET['callback']" from the echo and let me know. Just print $jsonp (why do you need to echo the callback variable?)

Comment: @ricardohdz: i saw that in some tutorial. After remove, my ajax call did not run the "success" function.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

//test.php file

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$array = array();
array_push($array, array('name' => 'A', 'host' => 'A.com'));
array_push($array, array('name' => 'B', 'host' => 'B.com'));

$jsonp = json_encode($array);

if(isset($_GET['callback'])){
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $jsonp . ')';
}else{
    echo $jsonp;
}
?>
```

//js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myCallback(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    }   

    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'myCallback',
        crossDomain: true,
        ifModified: true
    });
</script>
```

Remember, jQuery auto generates aliases for the callback if you do not specify it. Your callback was actually being set to `"jQuery191019304498913697898_1365868235193()"`. By manually setting your callback it should work.

Comment: JS-Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: myCallback is not defined

Comment: did you copy and paste all the code exactly? myCallback() needs to be defined where you are making the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 header('Content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');
```

to

```
 header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```